# Negate a statement and prove the negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Consider the following statement.
There exist integers $k$ and $m$ such that for all integers $x$ if $x\geq k$ then $x^2< m \cdot x$.
Disprove this statement.
(Hint: first write the negation of this statement then prove this negation.)

**My attempt**

The statement to disprove is $\exists(k, m) \ \forall x \ x\geq k \implies x^2 < m \cdot x $

$\neg(\exists(k, m) \ \forall x \ x\geq k \implies x^2 < m \cdot x ) = \forall(k, m) \ \exists x \ x\geq k \land \neg(x^2 < m \cdot x)$

$\neg(\exists(k, m) \ \forall x \ x\geq k \implies x^2 < m \cdot x )= \forall(k, m) \ \exists x \ x\geq k \land (x^2 \geq m \cdot x)$

The negation of the statement is  $\forall(k, m) \ \exists x \ x\geq k \land (x^2 \geq m \cdot x)$

**Question/help:**

How can I prove the negation of the statement ($\forall(k, m) \ \exists x \ x\geq k \land (x^2 \geq m \cdot x)$)?

Comment: Your negation is OK. You may want to take cases based on whether $m>0,\ m=0,\ m<0.$

Comment: Take $x = 1 + \max(|k|, |m|).$